# how to add Label to a THREE.Mesh?

Tags: javascript, three.js

The objective is to display the Three.Mesh name as a label while hovering the mouse over the mesh. How we can do this in Three.js

Can someone give a sample code ?

Comment: Are you trying to actually render the text as part of the scene? Does it need to be 3D text? Or will overlaying 2D markup on top of the renderer with CSS ok? Also you might want to accept some previous answers or not many will be inclined to help you.

Comment: i just need the label to be just like a tool tip. It would be better to have the label when the mouse hover ends/stops on a mesh. An overlaying 2D markup on top of the renderer with CSS should be ok. Also please let me know which of my question/answers remain unaccepted. I just looked and hope none remains unaccepted. I have seen such labels in XTK.js API

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Challenge accepted!

Working code example at:
http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Mouse-Tooltip.html

There appear to be three major steps to this goal, each of which I have broken into smaller example programs.

(1) Determine which scene element the mouse is pointed over.
See: http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Mouse-Over.html

(2) Render the text you want to display as an image (I used a canvas element for this).
See: http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Texture-From-Canvas.html

(3) Draw a sprite containing the image from part (2) at the location of the mouse pointer.
See: http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Mouse-Sprite.html

All these examples (and more) are part of my growing collection of introductory examples (with detailed comments) at http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/ , in which I am trying to showcase the possibilities of Three.js in a series of minimal examples.

Also, credit where it's due: parts (1) and (3) are based on some of MrDoob's examples on his github page, specifically the interactive cubes example: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Lee Stemkoshi. Your examples are awesome and really helpful.

Comment: @lee Is there any way with latest version ...I warnings and  errors with current version ... it's V71

Comment: It there a simpler solution to this now? Example if you have skinnedmeshes on the scene and want to display the names on top of each mesh? Problem with sprites now is it scales in and out depending on the zoom. I want it to remain the same. It should just follow the mesh around (stay on the head).

Comment: Hi there, all of these links are now broken. Any chance of some code in the answer? (side note — SO recommends any answers have code in the answer not just links for this reason)

Comment: here are updated links: https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/tree/master/Three.js
and 
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html