# How to add label to sphere in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am new to three.js but here is what I am trying to do.

I have a sphere.. and I want to add an id label at a distance (say) 2 units to its surface.

So

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 50, 25, 25 );
 var draw_object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {  color: Math.random() * 0xffffff, opacity: 0.5 } ) ] );
```

now I want to give it a name "sphere 1"

and then at a distance "x" units from surface of sphere.. assign a label to it.
The catch is this sphere moves in space..so the label has to stay with it.

I have been trying since past two days without any luck.

Help
Any s

Comment: Have you checked out this previous question? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447821/how-to-add-label-to-a-three-mesh

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to use a Sprite as in the example referenced above ([how to add Label to a THREE.Mesh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447821/how-to-add-label-to-a-three-mesh)) However, instead of setting the position to be the mouse coordinates, calculate the offset from the sphere -- say it was, for example, (3,4,5) -- and do something like

```
label.position.set( sphere.position.add( new THREE.Vector3(3,4,5) ) );
```

This way, the label's position stores a reference to the sphere's position, and as the sphere moves the label will move with it.