# How to add label to THREE.Mesh when a part of 3D Object is double clicked?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, sprite

3D object is rendered using three.js.

Double click any part of the 3D object.

The objective is to display a label(2D label) near the part, describing the 3D Object part that is double-clicked by the user. The label should be displayed at the point where user double-clicked the part and always face the camera.

How to display the label like a callout(shape) or display an image, instead of the rounded rectangle as shown in three.js examples?

Can someone give a sample code ?

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: @prisoner849 Yes, i have tried adding the label to a part of 3D object clicked by creating Sprite using three.js. It works. However not getting how to hide it on clicking elsewhere. And how to change the shape to callout where the label will be displayed.

Comment: These are very broad questions and there are simply too many different ways to accomplish what you're after... For instance, you're not saying whether that label has to be part of the 3D scene. If not, you could easily resort to the dom... Can you post any specific code ?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, or at least post some image which explains what is expected.

Comment: @Pradip Shenolkar , Updated with the code i have tried.
i would like to know how to hide(/remove) the sprite of previously selected part, when i click on another part/outside the 3D object.
Also looking for any help suggesting how to change the shape(rounded rectangle) in which the label is displayed.

Comment: @Ams does your label have to be part of the 3d scene ? If not, you could  simply use a div and position it over the rendered scene

Comment: @Hesha can you please post a sample code snippet showing how a div can be positioned over the part at the point where the mouse double clicked that part of 3D object?

Comment: I'll cook up a fiddle for you later today ok. In the meantime... you should take a look at Raycasting

Comment: @Hesha okay.. I wanted to confirm one more thing, will the div created dynamically always look at the camera? Irrespective of rotating the 3D Object.. In my task i want that label positioned always at the point where mouse double clicked the 3D object part and always looking at the camera. So i think the div position will have to be updated whenever the 3D object is transformed(rotate/zoom). Hence the confusion - when to use Sprite and when to create a div to dynamically add label on 3D object(rendered using three.js) part double clicked ?

Comment: Did you even bother searching? questions on how to add labels has been asked many times. look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447821/how-to-add-label-to-a-three-mesh). To add it with double click, just listen for the 'dblckick' event. To remove on click, add a click event listener when label is shown, then remove it again when label is hidden.

Comment: The answer depends on your actual needs, which you just made a tad clearer. Pros of div : reading, structuring and updating are easy. Cons : messy screen if you got many of them  (depending on size) and perf can be an issue  (loads of CSS transitions). Pros of Sprite : great perf, is part of the 3d world. Cons : structuring and updating the text content can be challenging depending the Sprite complexity.

Comment: Thanks all.. i am successful creating a **Sprite** (Text sprite to display a label) at the point where mouse double clicked the 3D object. This label always looks at the camera whenever 3D object is transformed.